# Can my husband ask my hand from my uncle not my dad?

Tags: nikah

I did not know my dad for the most part of my life.

After I did, he did not treat me like he treats his other daughters.

I do not have a good relationship with him. So, I want my husband to go to my uncle who raised me, not my father.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Your father must be asked first. If he refuses to arrange the marriage, then you might pass to the next wali in line.

[some say](http://islamqa.info/en/95405)

> If the wali repeatedly refuses the proposal of a compatible suitor, he
>   is to be regarded as preventing the marriage of the female relative
>   under his care, and his guardianship is thus rendered null and void,
>   and that right is transferred to the next closest relative on the
>   father’s side.

That being said, I don't know how Islam considers a wali who abandoned is ...wali-hood (?)... If your father never was a father to you, if he relinquished his right to be your father from your young age, I don't know if he can still be considered for the position of Wali. Maybe that's the question you should ask.